# ¿Cómo consultar dos tablas en un mismo formulario?

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una pequeña app para el control de escrutinio de las elecciones en el cual cargo las mesas donde se van a votas y los partidos políticos participantes. Para cargar la votación necesito seleccionar la mesa y que me muestre la lista de los partidos políticos con el numero de lista y el nombre del partido.

Estoy utilizando Django 2.2 para el desarrollo de la app web.

el archivo models.py de la app mesa es:

```
class Mesa(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    escuela = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

el archivo models.py de la app partido es:

```
class Partido(models.Model):
    lista = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pres = models.BooleanField()
    dip = models.BooleanField()
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre lo que necesito?

Comment: ¿Quieres mostrar los forms del modelo `Mesa` y del modelo `Partido`en un HTML, juntos?

Comment: Enteindo que quieres una lista de partidos dinamica,  que de acuerdo a la mesa que selecciones te muestre los partidos. Esto lo tienes que hacer con ajax, hasta donde sé no se  puede hacer en el forms directamente

Comment: @JulioCesar claro, eso es lo que quiero hacer. Hasta ahora o me muestra solo `Mesa` o solo `Partido` pero no logro que muestre ambos

Comment: @PabloArismendi para hacer eso, tendrías que adaptar la vista `CreateView` a trabajar con 2 formularios, pero la vista `CreateView` no fue diseñada para eso, así que sera una tarea difícil y ademas no se si seria de buena practica hacerlo, otra forma mas viable seria crear una vista "personalizada" por así decirlo, que trabaje por defecto ya con varios formularios.